# Uncrustify + Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, uncrustify

I'm having trouble getting uncrustify to format C++ lambdas

this is what it turns my lambda into:

```
auto print = [](auto const &i, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type)
             {
                 qDebug() << i;
             };
```

This is what I would like:

```
auto print = [](auto const &i, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type)
{
    qDebug() << i;
};
```

Doe anyone now what setting is responsible for the positioning of the braces?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your Uncrustify config file?

Comment: Here you go [link](http://pastebin.com/dGcfMEaJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your config file, it seems there are a few rogue settings:

1. At line 223

   ```
   # Align continued statements at the '='. Default=True
   # If FALSE or the '=' is followed by a newline, the next line is indent one tab.
   indent_align_assign                       = true     # false/true
   ```

   As you can see, you are assigning a lambda to a symbol. Additional newlines are configured to align themselves with the `=` sign of the assignment.
2. At lines 830 and 833

   ```
   # The span for aligning on '=' in assignments (0=don't align)
   align_assign_span                         = 1        # number

   # The threshold for aligning on '=' in assignments (0=no limit)
   align_assign_thresh                       = 0        # number
   ```

   If you don't feel like changing the config at line 223, maybe you can try playing around with this pair of settings.

If changing any of those settings is not really plausible for you, you might have to make some serious code style reforms. For one, I see that the example lambda is suitable as one line statement. Maybe keep them in single lines. (They will stay that way as Line 964 in your config file ensures that).

Comment: Thanks for going through it in such detail. The 830/833 don't help as the lambas span a few lines (in their current state) span multiple lines, so the span will need be like 6, which will conflict with others. So far the line 223 edit seems to do what I want. I'll go with that for now.I don't want to make these lambas one liners as their argument list is huge